# cookie.Expire is not working in chrome

Tags: c#, cookies, setcookie

Hi i come across very strange Problem in chrome.I have following code for Cookie.

```
 HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("cookie");
 cookie.Value = "true";
 cookie.Expires.AddDays(30);
 Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Now above code is not working in chrome while its working well in FF and IE.If i check this cookie in chrome then its there but cookie Expire date is like **When the browsing session ends** in chrome.

that means if i Close the Browser then the cookie will expire instead of expiring after 30 days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use DateTime.Now/DateTime.UtcNow:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("cookie");
cookie.Value = "true";
cookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```